# Google Directions API not providing exact steps

Tags: google-maps

I'm using [Google Directions API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/) to get directions between 2 locations. I'm able to get the Webservice response (json) and draw a line over the map.

However, I noticed that the direction steps are quite less in the response thus making the lines not follow exact road curves. This is for any location, for [example](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Hall%20Bazar&destination=Majitha%20Road&sensor=true).

When I search the locations on Google Maps, I can see lines drawn exactly over road curves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps received in the Webservice response are the turn points where the user's direction will change.

I now tried to get the polyline from the webservice response and extracted coordinates with code provided [here](http://fkn1337.com/decode-google-maps-polylines-objective-c/). Problem resolved!

Comment: Using the json response example [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/get-directions#DirectionsResponses) I found that I was actually just calling the `overview_polyline` points instead of each `polyline` value from the `step` of each respective `leg` (all of which constitute a route's accurate polyline).